# Extrema for a Function on a Closed Disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to verify my procedure to find if the extrema is correct for a function
$u \left( x,y \right) ={x}^{2}-{y}^{2}$ on the set $\left( \mathop{\rm D}~~=~\left\{\left(x ,y \right)
\in \mathbb{R}^{2}{\it} | x ^{2}+y ^{2}
\le 1\right\} \right)
$

By the closed interval method, to find the absolute maximum and minimum values of a continuous function u on a closed, bounded set D,

1. Find the values of u at the critical points of u in D: 
   $u_{{x}} \left( x,y \right) =2\,x$ = 0 and 
   $u_{{y}} \left( x,y \right) =-2\,y$ = 0
   and so (x,y) = (0,0) is the only critical point on the unit disk.
2. Find the extreme values of u on the boundary of the unit disk:
   From ${y}^{2}=-{x}^{2}+1$, v(x) = $u \left( x,y \right) ={x}^{2}-{y}^{2}$ = ${2x}^2-1$
   and 
   v'(x) = 4x.

So, the solution of u at the critical point is x = 0.

The unit circle is bounded by -1 ≤ x ≤ 1, and so the corresponding values to the points of x are:

v(0) = -1, v(-1) = 1, v(1) = 1

Comment: When $y^2=-x^2+1$, $u(x,y)=2x^2-1$ and not $-1$

Comment: (0,0) is a critical point but it is not an extrema (look at the Hermitian matrix)

Comment: By the way, you've got a continuous function on an compact so there must be a maximum and a minimum

Comment: Correct. That was my confusion, and now I see the silly algebraic error.

Comment: I am not sure that you can use the closed interval method in your case, as you have a closed ** curve**. In the former case you evaluate the function at the extreme values of the closed interval, however here you can't evaluate your function at each point of the curve !(indeed you have infinity points on  $x^2+y^2=1$).  By the way ,  $u_y(x,y)=-2y$.

Answer (score 1):

the critical values on $D$ are the solution of the System
$$2x=0$$
$$2y=0$$
for the others we consider
$$F(x,y)=x^2-y^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)$$
and you must solve
$$2x+2x\lambda=0$$
$$-2y+\lambda2y=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you, in a similar strategy, to use    [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

So you first study  the max and min  of  $f$ in the  open set  $x^2+y^2< 1$, as you see in your case there is no min no max  of  $f$ in this region, because the only critical point is  $(0,0)$, and  the  hesien matrix of  $f$  at  $(0,0)$ is  $$\begin{pmatrix}  2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix} $$ which is neither  positive nor negative definite.

Now for the boundary  i.e. at   $x^2+y^2=1$ you may use optimization of  $f(x,y)$ using the constraint  $g(x,y)=0$, with  $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$.  Then use the Lagrange multiplier to find the min and the max of  $f$.